# mongodb - extract a particular value in an embedded array within an array

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I'm fairly new to mongoDB, but I've managed to archive a load of documents into a new collection called documents_archived in the following format using an aggregation pipeleine:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a0046ef2039404645a42f52"),
    "archive" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("54e60f49e4b097cc823afe8c"),
            "_class" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "fields" : [
                {
                    "key" : "Agreement Number",
                    "value" : "1002465507"
                }
                {
                    "key" : "Name",
                    "value" : "xxxxxxxx"
                }
                {
                    "key" : "Reg No",
                    "value" : "xxxxxxx"
                }
                {
                    "key" : "Surname",
                    "value" : "xxxxxxxx"
                }
                {
                    "key" : "Workflow Id",
                    "value" : "xxxxxxxx"
                }
             ],
             "fileName" : "Audit_C1002465507.txt",
             "type" : "Workflow Audit",
             "fileSize" : NumberLong(404),
             "document" : BinData(0, "xxxxx"),
             "creationDate" : ISODate("2009-09-25T00:00:00.000+0000"),
             "lastModificationDate" : ISODate("2015-02-19T16:28:57.016+0000"),
             "expiryDate" : ISODate("2018-09-25T00:00:00.000+0000")
         }
     ]
```

}

Now, I'm trying to extract just the Agreement Number's value. However, I have tried many things that my limited knowledge, searching and documentation will allow. Wondered if the mongoDB experts out there can help. Thank you.

Comment: Does the `archive` array always have one element?

Comment: yes it only has one element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses the agg framework.  I am assuming that each doc can have more than one entry in the `archive` field but only one `Agreement Number` in the fields array because your design appears to be key/value.   If multiple `Agreement Numbers` show up in the fields array we'll have to add an additional `$unwind` but for the moment, this should work:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$archive"}
  ,{$project: {x: {$filter: {
            input: "$archive.fields",
            as: "z",
            cond: {$eq: [ "$$z.key", "Agreement Number" ]}
        }}
  }}
  ,{$project: {_id:false, val: {$arrayElemAt: ["$x.value",0]} }}
]);

{ "val" : "1002465507" }
```

Comment: Hi, each document contains the same structure of the fields array, so there would be no multiple agreement numbers, just one, as per the example above.

Comment: So you're all good with this then.   foo blob and zip came from test which had 4 separate docs.

Comment: If I just wanted the value of the agreement number and nothing else how can that be achieved, through another projection aggregation stage ?

Comment: Well, you can always "suppress" _id with   
  ,{$project: {_id:false, val: {$arrayElemAt: ["$x.value",0]} }}
But you have to get SOME kind of record back; that's the nature of the API.  When you say "nothing else", exactly what kind of variable holding what data would you like to be presented back to your app?

Comment: In theory, just the agreement number i,e 1002465507

Comment: MongoDB does not vend "naked scalars" through the APIs.   The basic carrier is a Document which is a name:value pair.    Is   {val:"1002465507"} too much?

Comment: No, that would be absolutely fine.

Comment: OK then.  I changed answer above to hold back _id from the emitted output, yielding only {val:"1002465507"}

Answer (score 0):

You can use following in mongo shell to extract only values:

```
db.documents_archived.find().forEach(function(doc) {
doc.archive[0].fields.forEach(function(field) {
    if (field.key == "Agreement Number") {
        print(field.value)
    }
})
```

})